# How to put an R script into a dockerfile?

Tags: r, macos, docker, terminal, dockerfile

I am trying to add my R script into a dockerfile. The beginning of the file (loading base image, installing necessary packages) works fine when I run it in my terminal, but I keep getting this error when it gets to the line that contains the R script I want to run:

```
Step 15/17 : COPY /Users/emma/Documents/folder1/examples/question-1/model-1.r .

COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder376572603/Users/emma/Documents/folder1/examples/question-1/model-1.r: no such file or directory
```

I am already running the terminal out of the "question-1" directory (my shell command looks like this) :

```
Emmas-MacBook-Air-2:question-1 emma$
```

and the R script file "model-1.r" is in that folder. What am I doing wrong in detailing the path to the R script? Do I have to somehow transform the script before adding it to the dockerfile?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, that you have to specify relative (to your build folder) path to copy from. [Source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy):

> Multiple  resources may be specified but the paths of files and directories will be interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build.

And file to copy should be inside context of the build. So if your Dockerfile is located in folder A, then the objects you would like to copy should be placed in the folder A or it's subfolders.

Comment: I will confirm that this is true. Any file that should be copied from local to the docker image, has to be placed within the file-subsystem that contains the dockerfile. In addition files should be copied immediately before the specific `RUN` command for it to be available, making it beneficial to concatenate `RUN` commands using a backslash (\\) after each line. Copying entire folders is possible as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I have been trying to get this to work for days.

Comment: @Emma No problem. I have faced these limitations some time ago.